# MVEL null value in equality operator

Tags: java, mvel

If I have this script in MVEL:

```
myString = null;

if (myString == "Foo") {
    return true;
}
```

Would I get a null pointer in this script?

Because I read the documentation but it says the `==` operator is similar to the `.equals()` method in java which checks by value so will I get thrown a null pointer if one of the operands in my script is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get in trouble with the expression shown in the question. Try this instead:

```
if ("Foo" == myString)
```

It *looks* like a silly change, but given that `equals()` is being [called under the hood](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/MVEL_Language_Guide#Value_Tests), the above will translate to:

```
if ("Foo".equals(null))
```

Which is fine, unlike this, which is what you had before:

```
if (null.equals("Foo"))
```

Comment: That is a nice little trick, but I'm curious if the equals method actually IS called under the hood. I currently don't have the development environment to test it

Comment: Yes it is, according to this [documentation](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/MVEL_Language_Guide#Value_Tests)

Comment: That just says its equivalent to - it does not necessarily mean it is called.